# How to import the xml into another xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, jaxb, xinclude

I have 2 xml files, and in the first file need to do the import second file, I tried to do it with [Xinclude](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#syntax):

*first.xml:*

```
<FirstXml name="first" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="second.xml"/>
</FirstXml>
```

*second.xml*

```
<SecondXml name="second>
  ...
</SecondXml>
```

Then I tried to create an instance of a DocumentBuilderFactory and to enable XInclude processing.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setXIncludeAware(true);
```

But when I try to enable the  XInclude processing throws an UnsupportedOperationException.

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setXIncludeAware(boolean)) says that this exception throws when implementations for earlier versions of JAXP is used.

How can I fix this problem? Or how I can do such import in android?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_starting"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

you can try these to import the second layout.

Comment: Thank you, but I need import usual xml, not layout

Answer (score 0):

just write the below line in your first.xml file

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_layout" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need import usual xml from xml resource directory, not layout